# Is there a way to have the @MethodSource arguments parameters derived from another method

Tags: junit5, parameterized

I have a Junit 5 non static parameterized test where I am using @MethodSource to get the test data.

The Method Source arguments are getting the data from other methods as below code. I made the @MethodSource non static by having a
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)

The fullDomain parameter in the @MethodSource is derived from the method getFullDomain() in the registrationPage which is also non static .  I @Autowired the RegistrationPage in the BaseTest and using it by extending in my Junit5SampleTest Class

When I run the test the fullDomain is returning null. Is there a way to fix this or can I use any others like @ArgumentSource to fix this.

I will need to get the Arguments.of("Successful Regisration", fullDomain)  data from different classes and its methods.

Base Test:

```
public class BaseTest {
@Autowired
protected RegistrationPage registrationPage;
}
```

Test Class:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Junit5SampleTest extends BaseTest {

String fullDomain = registrationPage.getFullDomain();

Stream<Arguments> registrationInputParameters() {
     return Stream.of(
             Arguments.of("Successful Regisration", fullDomain)        
 }

@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource("registrationInputParameters")
public  void junit5(String testName, String fullDomain){
System.out.println(testName);
open(fullDomain);
}
}
```